# Django - What is the most efficient way to query the average ratings for a list of objects?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a simple Product and Rating class like so:

```
class Product(models.Model):
   name = ...
   price = ...

class Rating(models.Model):
   product = models.ForeignKey("Product", ...)
   score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(...)
```

Now I want to get a list all products and the average rating for each product. Simply getting all products is easy:

```
product_list = Product.objects.all()
```

If I have a single product and I want to get the average rating for that single product:

```
product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
ratings = Rating.objects.filter(product=product)
product_avg_rating = ratings.aggregate((Avg("score")))
```

But let's assume I want to list all products and their average rating. This sounds like it's quite resource/compute heavy. So what is the best way to solve this? Should I make a class method for the Product class that just returns the average, so I can then call this in the template:

```
{{ product.get_average_rating }}
```

Or is there a better way to do this? I'm not quite sure what to do here and need some guidance.

Thank you so much in advance!

EDIT: I think I wasn't clear enough with my explanation, so here's an actual example. Let's say I have a query set, filtered by the slug (which is just a searchterm):

```
products = Product.objects.filter(tags__name__in=[slug])
```

Now how can I add the average rating to EACH SINGLE product so that I can do this in the template:

```
{% for product in products %}
   {{ product.avg_rating_score }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Annotate it already in the first `get_object_or_404` query.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand. How can I connect the average from a different model (namely: Rating) to my list of products? And how would I print it out in a template? {{ product.??? }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate your `Product` in the first query, so that it will only take *one* query to obtain the average, like:

```
product = get_object_or_404(
    Product.object.annotate(avg_score=Avg('rating__score')),
    pk=product_id
)
```

This will result in a single `Product` that contains an extra attribute (only for *this* specific `QuerySet`!), in the template, we thus can render it with:

```
{{ product.avg_score }}
```

The query that it does is:

```
SELECT product.*, AVG(rating.score) AS avg_score
FROM product
LEFT OUTER JOIN rating ON product.id = rating.product_id
WHERE product.id = product_id
```

Comment: You would use the related name for product ratings - ...Avg('rating_set__score')...

Comment: @JehoshaphAkshay: well I tested it, and the name of the model works. Personally I prefer the name of the model *unless* there are multiple relations, or unless the name is quite different than the model name. The reason is that typically the name of the model will change less likely, and thus it is a bit "more stable".

Comment: Hmm but how do I add it to multiple elements within a queryset? I updated my original post with an example so it's easier to understand.

Comment: @casualcoder: that's still the same, except that you of course do not use `get_object_or_404`.